# How can I set ng-style attribute to be equal to object value?

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angular-ui

What I need is to set color of output text to a selected color, I figured out that I should use ng-style but i dont know how.

Plunker code:

```
<html>http://plnkr.co/edit/XFCMcjwYtxIInc8lMQaC?p=preview</html>
```

For example, when you create group you get groupname - selectedcolorfromform, I need groupname to be coloured in selected color

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add `ng-style="{color : model.color}"`

See an example here: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngStyle

http://plnkr.co/edit/rOUwOUR1s3OPHsnG2Qh0?p=preview

Comment: I need groupname to be coloured in selected color but not in form field but in the output. After you create group you get groupname - selectedcolorfromform in the white space on page, I need groupname to be coloured in selected color